# Postgresql index corruption cause - postgresql bug or hardware failure

Tags: database, postgresql

I have postgresql 9.5.2 production server which was having some serious problems with indexes.  The strongest piece of evidence supporting that claim is inconsistency between some queries:

```
select count(*) from x inner join y on x.a = y.a
select *        from x inner join y on x.a = y.a
```

The count(*) query would return a different number than the number of rows returned by the select * query, which just returned rows.  The first thing I tried was a vacuum analyze, but that didn't fix the problem.  Eventually, in order to get the server working again, dropped all indexes and rebuilt them, at which point the results became consistent between the select * and select count(*) queries.

Neither table has any triggers.  Table x has 1.7 million rows, and table y has 6.9 million rows and 600,000 deleted rows, and the tables are linked using a foreign key field a, which is the primary key in table x, and a not null foreign key constraint in table b.  The database server is hosted in a virtual machine.  The server is the only node, and there is no replication to other servers.  The system has never crashed, so while I know that a crashing server or postgres service can corrupt indexes, I have no reason to believe either of these happened because a) the postgres service has never been not available and b) the server indicates it has been up for a very long time, well before this problem manifested itself.

All of this data suggests that the problem was an index was not working correctly.  My research on corrupted indexes generally points to two causes, bugs in postgresql or hardware failure.

The solution to a hardware failure and a bug in the database itself are solved using radically different techniques, namely one involves purchasing hardware and the other involves writing programs to check the integrity of the indexes and taking appropriate action if necessary to correct the problems.

What pieces of evidence can I collect in favor of each theory (hardware failure vs. software bug)?

Answer (score 0):

The best safeguard against hardware problems is to enable page checksums by using the `--data-checksums` option of `initdb` when creating the cluster.
But that won't help investigate past problems, and it requires a dump/reload of the database cluster.

If you do physical backups (with `pg_basebackup` or with `pg_start_backup()` and `pg_stop_backup`), it would be interesting to find the last backup where things were still ok. That might be tedious, but it will narrow down the window where to look for problems.

Do you have `fsync = off` or `full_page_writes = off`? Or are you using [unreliable storage](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/wal-reliability.html)? Then your database can be corrupted by a crash even if there is no bug and the hardware is fine. Check the database log for crashes.

To find out if you are suffering from hardware problems, look at the operating system log files and perform hardware tests.

To check for known software problems, look at the [release notes](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/release.html). If you have a corrupt index, you can ask the pgsql-hackers [mailing list](https://www.postgresql.org/list/) for help.

Comment: We do backups using pg_dump, which backs up the existence of the indexes, but I don't think it would copy the index itself.  The system hosting the server has not crashed, and to the best of my knowledge the postgresql server did not crash either.